# Is there any setting in IIS/machine.config that could prevent my application from making REST requests?

Tags: rest, iis

I'm facing a funny issue here.

I got a C# Webforms application running on IIS6. When the user clicks on a certain link, my app makes a REST call to a webservice hosted in the cloud. This call, made by the app running on IIS, fails. We get a WebException, with the message "no response from server".

However, if I try to connect to the same web service, from the same machine, with the same credentials, using SoapUI, the call succeeds. So I guess this means that I can rule out firewall issues, credential issues, and availability of the service.

The code has been tested on numerous other machines (dev, test, staging...), and it worked successfully, so the code itself should not be an issue. I think it's an environmental issue (a setting on web.config or machine.config which prevents outgoing requests).

Any idea as to what that could be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason our REST calls were failing was that we were missing an SSL certificate.

We were trying to make the REST call using HTTPS. The REST service provider's SSL certificate was signed by a well-known CA. However, our server apparently had a hardened build, and the CA's certificate was missing from the certificate repository. Hence, the provider's SSL certificate was considered unsafe.

Sadly, the .Net framework exception had no useful information about this.

We installed the CA's certificate and the issue was fixed.